# Node.js async function not being recognized as a valid async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I've got these 2 functions

```js
async function movieExists(movie){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sql = '...';

            con.query(sql, (err,result,fields) => {
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                else if(!result[0])
                    reject("Error");
                else
                    resolve(result[0].total);
            })
        })
}
```

```js
async function addMovie(movie){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sql = '...';
            const exists = await movieExists(movie); //Error on this line

            if(exists == 0){
                con.query(sql, (err,result,fields) => {
                    if(err)
                        reject("Error");
                    else   
                        resolve("Success");
                })
            }else
                resolve("Movie already exists");
        })
}
```

Error : 
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Node version -> v10.16.0

**If you have any suggestions for the code itself I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: `(resolve, reject) => {` that's the function that isn't async ... the fact that it's a promise constructor also suggests you're guilty of the Promise constructor anti-pattern ... you already have something that returns a promise ... you don't need to construct a promise

Comment: move the `new Promise` line down two lines - problem solved

Comment: What is `con`? Most DB connection libraries on NPM now offer promise-based APIs. Would save you a lot of headache and no more `new Promise(...`

Comment: I'd actually suggest switching to the musql2 version of your database which has built-in promise support.  Then, you can use promises for all your database operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The await keyword is directly inside the function that you are passing to `new Promise()`, which is not async.

Try moving it outside that function, like this:

```
async function addMovie(movie){
  const exists = await movieExists(movie);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = '...';
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: On the Promise antipattern others are talking about you might want to look at [util.promisify()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) (added in node 8.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

The second condition is wrong because in the Promise the anonymous function is not async function you can use the following instead, but it is not a good way to control the sequence of async.

```
async function addMovie(movie){
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const sql = '...';
            const exists = await movieExists(movie); //Error on this line

            if(exists == 0){
                con.query(sql, (err,result,fields) => {
                    if(err)
                        reject("Error");
                    else   
                        resolve("Success");
                })
            }else
                resolve("Movie already exists");
        })
}
```